# Catch bad URLs when using EaselJS bitmap

Tags: javascript, error-handling, easeljs

Is there a way to check whether a URL leads to a valid image or not before trying to load it into a createjs.Bitmap?  I've been trying to catch the error of a bad URL (in Firefox), but for some reason that doesn't work.

```
    try {

        image = new createjs.Bitmap ( "image" );

    } catch ( err ) {

        console.log ( "oops" );
        return null;

    }
```

When I run this code in Firefox the error still shows up in the console, and the logged message doesn't.  My question is, then, is there a way to pre-validate the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is bad, undefined, null, etc - it will **not** `throw` an error, so try/catch will do nothing.

If you use [PreloadJS](http://preloadjs.com) (part of the CreateJS suite) to load the image, you can listen for an `error` event, which the queue will throw if any images fail to load (or time out).

```
var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
queue.on("error", handleError);
queue.loadFile("404image.png");
```

There is currently no built-in way using just a raw `Bitmap` instance to determine if an error happens. Images passed by string path to Bitmap are not preloaded, but are just internally requested using an Image instance.

Comment: Hmm, alright.  That seems like it should work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use normal JS to detect if the image can be loaded and if so pass that instance to the EaselJS `Bitmap`:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    console.log('img loaded');
    var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(img);
}
img.onerror = function() {
    console.log('error');
} 
img.src = 'notexistingimage.png';
```

Comment: I tried doing a little bit of this, but I still had some issues with the errors.

Comment: What kind of issues? Can you please provide further information.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out.  I was using the code you gave here, but then I had the call to stage.addChild() outside of the onload portion by accident.  So, that didn't work.  Also, apparently when making a bitmap it won't throw create a problem over a bad URL until the code calls the addChild method.